# SpriteKit Jumping when hitting Ground

Tags: sprite-kit, intersection, touchesbegan

So I got 2 SKSpriteNodes, a Human and a Block. If the Human hits the block on the top, it should be able to jump, if he is in the air, he shouldn't. I am using intersectsNode, but then the Human only jumps at the end of the Block, and I don't really know why.
A Member of the Forum told me to use bodyAtPoint, but if I use it it only shows : 
"there is no visible @interface for SKSpriteNode declares the selector bodyAtPoint".

My current Code with intersectsNode :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

Human.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
if([Human intersectsNode:Block1]){
[Human.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 40)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the `didBeginContact:` instead of `intersectsNode`. In MyScene you can set it up like this:

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    BOOL playerBlockContact
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryPlayer | CNPhysicsCategoryBlock))
    {
        playerBlockContact = true;
        NSLog(@"Contact");
    }
}

- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
    if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryPlayer | CNPhysicsCategoryBlock))
    {
        playerBlockContact = false;
        NSLog(@"Contact lost");
    }
}
```

Then replace your `if([Human intersectsNode:Block1])` with `If(playerBlockContact)`.